# Error when trying to change Caching Application

Tags: magento2.3, cache, magento2.3.2, full-page-cache, litespeed

I was trying to get a Magento 2.3.2 store to use a different caching mechanism rather than the built in one but every time I attempt to change this I am met with a 500 error and the store just reverts back to the default caching. I have ruled out any issues with the caching application I am trying to use as attempting to switch to any other method including the built in cache results in the same error.

Whenever I recreate this, the following error appears in the error.log

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Magento\Config\Model\Config::getOriginalFieldId() must be an instance of Magento\Config\Model\Config\Structure\Element\Group, instance of Magento\Config\Model\Config\Structure\Element\Field\Interceptor given, called in /vendor/magento/module-config/Model/Config.php on line 279 and defined in /vendor/magento/module-config/Model/Config.php:248
Stack trace:
#0 /vendor/magento/module-config/Model/Config.php(279): Magento\Config\Model\Config->getOriginalFieldId(Object(Magento\Config\Model\Config\Structure\Element\Field\Interceptor), 'use_separate_pr...')
#1 /vendor/magento/module-config/Model/Config.php(429): Magento\Config\Model\Config->getField('system/cron', 'template', 'use_separate_pr...')
#2 /vendor/magento/module-config/Model/Config.php(488): Magento\Config\Model\Config->_processGroup('template', Array, Array, 'system/cron', Array, Array,  in /vendor/magento/module-config/Model/Config.php on line 248
```

Has anyone else come across this problem before?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried removing the generated directory?

```
rm -rf generated
```

Comment: thanks for taking the time to answer this query, I've tried removing everything from generated, var/cache and var/page_cache but still resulting in the same error.

Answer (score 0):

After many hours of debugging I managed to resolve this. It turns out to be an issue with the SalesFire extension that was installed. Disabling this extension prevented the errors from occurring and allowed the site to switch caching methods.